# Subtract/add days to Pandas Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

How do I subtract/add days (integer) to a Pandas Timestamp object?

For example, my atomics and datatypes are (lifted from Pycharm):

```
startDate = {Timestamp} 2008-09-20 00:00:00
dayDistance = {int} 124
```

The code as pulled from the Internet returns ***None***:

```
from datetime import timedelta
newDate = startDate - timedelta(days=dayDistance)
```

I am expecting an object of type **Timestamp** so it is compatible with the rest of the code downstream from here.

Answer (score 1):

pandas has its own Timedelta data type:

```py
start_date = pd.Timestamp("2008-09-20 00:00:00")
dayDistance = 124

new_date = start_date - pd.Timedelta(dayDistance, unit="d")
```

But Python's built-in `timedelta` works too:

```py
from datetime import timedelta
new_date = start_date - timedelta(days=dayDistance)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it works fine on my test. But you may use [pd.Timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) instead

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

ts = pd.Timestamp.now()
print(f"{type(ts)} {ts}")
dt_td_ts = ts - timedelta(days=10)
pd_td_ts = ts - pd.Timedelta(10, unit='d')
print(f"With datetime timedelta: ({type(dt_td_ts)}) {dt_td_ts}")
print(f"With pandas   timedelta: ({type(pd_td_ts)}) {pd_td_ts}")
```

returns

```
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'> 2022-05-15 22:20:04.596195
With datetime timedelta: (<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>) 2022-05-05 22:20:04.596195
With pandas   timedelta: (<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>) 2022-05-05 22:20:04.596195
```

as you can see the type is `Timestamp` as expected even when using `datetime.timedelta`